# How to render PHP output to initialise a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I wan to call a PHP function in JavaScript code that echoes out a value:

```
<?php
function ex()
{
  $num=10;
  echo($num);
} 
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  function sam_click(clicked)
  {
    var x="<?php ex(); ?>";
    alert(x);
    return false;
  }
</script>'?>
```

However, it doesn't work. Can you help?

Comment: You're trying to call the function inside of a `String`.

Comment: For the love of all that is good, please do not put 'wanna' in your titles. Txtspk dz nt blg hr, thx!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
function ex()
{
  $num=10;
  echo($num);
} 
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  function sam_click(clicked)
  {
    var x="' . ex() . '>";
    alert(x);
    return false;
  }
</script>'?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
...
var x="' . ex() . '";
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try echoing only what you need

```
<?php
function ex()
{
  $num=10;
  echo($num);
} 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function sam_click(clicked)
  {
    var x="<?php ex(); ?>";
    alert(x);
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: +1 for this. Using echo for large blocks of code is not a great (nor pretty) practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ex()
{
    $num=10;
    echo $num;
    return $num; // if you want to get JS alert
}
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
function sam_click(clicked)
{
    var x='.ex().';
    alert(x);
    return false;
}
sam_click(); // if you want to get JS alert
</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of echoing the $num, return it as a result and then append it in the script part.

```
<?php
function ex()
{
  $num=10;
  return ($num);
} 
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  function sam_click(clicked)
  {
    var x="' . ex() . '";
    alert(x);
    return false;
  }
</script>'?>
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution with heredoc and nowdoc:

```
<?php

// helper to call functions as nowdoc
// example: {$fn( function() )}
function fn($functionCall) 
{
  return $functionCall;
}
$fn = 'fn';

function ex()
{
  return 20;
}

$js = <<<EOT
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sam_click(clicked)
  {
    var x="{$fn(ex())}";
    alert(x);
    return false;
  }
</script>
EOT;

echo $js;
```

---

**Find more detail on PHPDoc:**

- [Nowdoc (PHP5.3+)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)
- [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)
- [Anonymous Functions (PHP5.3+)](http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php)